# Write a class "AntraMath" & Constructor function along with defining functions "add" , "multiply", and "done" So that the value of "res" printed is 30

Tags: javascript, methods, constructor

***Code Snippet:***

```
let myMath = new AntraMath(10);

myMath.add(5);

myMath.multiply(2);

let res = myMath.done();

console.log(res);
```

***Constructor Function Attempt:***

```
function AntraMath (_value){

    let myMath = new AntraMath(10);

    myMath.add(5);

    myMath.multiply(2);

    let res = myMath.done();

    console.log(res);

}
```

I tried to create a Constructor function "AntraMath" & follow along with the errors given afterwards. But after setting up; I received "Output: [Done] exited with code=0" instead of receiving any error's or the desired output 30.

Thank you to who ever may be reading this along with any input given.

Comment: Please add the definition of your other functions, such as `add`, `multiply` and `done` to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to define a class (or prototype) and use it. Your code contains usage, but does not contain the definitions you need.

```js
class AntraMath {

    constructor(_value) {
        this._value = _value;
    }
    
    add(_value) {
        this._value += _value;
        return this;
    }
    
    multiply(_value) {
        this._value *= _value;
        return this;
    }

    done() {
        return this._value;
    }
}

    let myMath = new AntraMath(10);

    myMath.add(5);

    myMath.multiply(2);

    let res = myMath.done();

    console.log(res);
```